# How to check if event's date is within a date range?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have events (from an Event model) that have a `starts_at:` value in the form of a datetime. e.g.:

```
2016-02-18 11:00:00:00000
```

What I want to be able to do is check whether an event is starting this week. 
I want to be able to make a list of events that are occuring this week (starting from the latest Monday).

```
@events = @calendar.events.where( ... )
```

I thought something along the lines of this:

```
    start_week = Date.today.beginning_of_week(:monday).day()
    end_week = Date.today.beginning_of_week(:monday).day()+6
    range = start_week..end_week
    @events = @calendar.events.where(starts_at: in range)
```

But it doesn't take into account the month or year. Also I'm not sure how to write the 'where' clause. How should I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: ActiveRecord automatically transform range into query with BETWEEN sql operator: `@events = @calendar.events.where(starts_at: range)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
start_week = Date.today.beginning_of_week(:monday)
end_week = Date.today.beginning_of_week(:monday)+6
range = start_week..end_week
@events = @calendar.events.where(starts_at: range)
```

Comment: That just gives you a range of day numbers... (07..13) ... so you're comparing `starts_at:` to a range of numbers.  You should be doing a range of dates. It also fails if the month changes in the week.

Comment: Cool, that look's better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all the events from the current week, something like this should work:

`@events = @calendar.events.where(starts_at: Time.zone.today.all_week)`

[all_week](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_week) returns a Date range covering the current week.